# To find a sequence of one array into another array

Tags: c#

I have two array objects

```
int[] arr1= new int[] {1,2,5,6,7,9,3,5,6,7}
int[] arr2 = new int[] {5,6,7}
```

Now, how to find the no of occurrences of arr2 in arr1?

Comment: Do you want a count of how many 5,6,7 are in the first array or do you want an array with only the numbers present in both arrays?

Comment: Your problem needs are more precise specification. What should `arr1 = {1, 1, 1, 1}`, `arr2 = {1, 1}` return? 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi Steve, To clarify on the output, It has to return me the count as 2 since the sequence {5,6,7} is occurring two times in the arr1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not very elegant, but it should work.
This selects all subarrays in `a` having the same length of `b`, and checks how many are equal to `b`.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = {2, 3};

int count = 0;
int bl = b.Length;
for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - bl; i++)
{
    var suba = a.Skip(i).Take(bl);
    if (suba.SequenceEqual(b))
    count++;
}
```

N.B.: this solution considers overlapping subarrays, therefore if `a = {2, 2, 2}` and `b = {2, 2}`, the count will be `2`.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `arr2.Intersect(arr1).Count()`

So in your case it will return `3`, as 3 elements in `arr2` are present in `arr1`.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. It seems to be he/she's asking the number of subsequences in `a` that are equal to that in `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the intersect. This code snippet will solve your problem and print all duplicates, and show the count of each in arr1. Note that I am also using the Linq Distinct(), so that when looping common occurrences, I only check once and not more.

```
            int[] arr1= new int[] {1,2,5,6,7,9,3,5,6,7};
            int[] arr2 = new int[] {5,6,7};
            var listCommon = arr1.AsEnumerable().Where(arr2.AsEnumerable().Contains);

            foreach (var x in listCommon.Distinct()) {
                var numberOfOccurencesInArr1 = arr1.Where(y => y == x).Count();
                Console.WriteLine(x + " is : " + numberOfOccurencesInArr1.ToString() + " times in arr1");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

See MSDN for more information; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx

The listCommon will be the number of common items in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var results = (from a1 in arr1
              join a2 in arr2
              on a1 equals a2
              group arr1 by a1 into Group
              select new
              {
                  Number = Group.Key,
                  Times = Group.Count()
              });

foreach(var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Number+" "+result.Times);
```

Please check this solution using the following fiddle [.NET fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/nvMdpR)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    string result = string.Empty; ;
    int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
    int[] arr2 = new int[] { 5, 6, 7 };


    int count = arr2.Intersect(arr1).Count();

    if (count == arr2.Length)
    {
        result = "Found";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Not Found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many occurences of an integer of the second array are present in the first array then you could write

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] {1,2,5,6,7,9,3,5,6,7};
int[] arr2 = new int[] {5,6,7};

Dictionary<int, int> counter = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(int x in arr1)
{
    if(arr2.Contains(x))
    {
        if(counter.ContainsKey(x))
          counter[x]++;
        else
          counter[x] = 1;
     }     
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in counter)
   Console.WriteLine("Key=" + kvp.Key.ToString() + " is present " + kvp.Value.ToString() + " times");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 5, 6, 7 };
```

how to find the no of occurrences of arr2 in arr1?
If you are expecting the result to be `2`. Since the 5,6,7 appears twice in the arr1

try this

```
 var res = arr1.Where(x => arr2.Contains(x)).Count()/arr2.Count();
```

Comment: This is not correct, it returns `1` if `arr1 = { 5, 5, 5 }`.

Answer (score 0):

As you input is arrays you can use indexing to effectively count the number of occurrences of the subarrays in the main array:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.Length - arr2.Length + 1; i += 1) {
  if (arr1[i] != arr2[0])
    continue;
  var isSubarray = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < arr2.Length; ++j)
    if (arr1[i + j] != arr2[j]) {
      isSubarray = false;
      break;
    }
  if (isSubarray)
    count += 1;
}
```

The result will be 2 because 567 is found two times in 1256793567.

If the subarray can "overlap" itself (e.g. 11 in 111) all "overlaps" will be counted (e.g. the result will be 2 for this example). If that is not the intention you simply have to advance the index `i` at the end of the main loop to skip the found subarray.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToLookup` on the `int`s in the first count which are also in the second array. Then you just have to take the min-count of all groups since that's the greatest intersection:

```
var subsetGroups = arr1.Where(i1 => arr2.Contains(i1)).ToLookup(i => i);       
int minGroupCount = 0;
// check if all integers from the array are in the first at all
if(arr2.All(i => subsetGroups.Contains(i)))
{
    minGroupCount = subsetGroups.Min(g => g.Count()); // 2
}
```

Note that this approach doesn't care about the order and it also doesn't care about the number of duplicates in the second array. This might be desired or not.